# Spring: application-context.xml not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC project, the application can only find application-context.xml when I place it under 'src/main/resources' but not when I place it under the contextConfigLocation as specified in web.xml.  Both application-context.xml and servlet-context.xml reside under the same appServlet directory.
[image]
**web.xml**

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`<br/>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd`
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd`
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">`

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
     
    <beans:import resource="application-context.xml"/></beans:beans>`
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans`
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`
 
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context`
 
 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

```
<!-- SET default mail properties -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="mail.company.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="applicationMailer" class="sdcounty.dcss.cat.ApplicationMailer">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>
     
</beans>
```

**Calling Method**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import sdcounty.dcss.cat.ApplicationMailer;
@RequestMapping(value = "/Error", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {`
        
        //Create the application context
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
         
        //Get the mailer instance
        ApplicationMailer mailer = (ApplicationMailer) context.getBean("applicationMailer");

        //Error Message
        String errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception") + String.format("%n") +
                              (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type") + String.format("%n") +
                              (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri") + String.format("%n") +
                              (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name") + String.format("%n") +
                              //(Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code") + String.format("%n") +
                              (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message") + String.format("%n");

        //Send a composed mail
        mailer.sendMail("john.doe@company.com", "Error Report", errorMessage);}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at sdcounty.dcss.cat.controllers.ErrorController.handleError(ErrorController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Try `<import resource="classpath:application-context.xml" />`. It will search in the classpath.

Comment: try adding "/" at the beginning, that will look in the resource folders: <beans:import resource="/application-context.xml"/></beans:beans>`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I tried both these options -- adding a forward slash and the classpath*: and neither worked resulting in the same error message, :-(

Comment: <beans:import resource="classpath*:application-context.xml"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try enforcing the `ClassPathResource` using
`<import resource="classpath:application-context.xml" />` even better `<import resource="classpath*:application-context.xml" />`